# My JS program to display prime numbers showing undefined

Tags: javascript

```
let counter = 0;
for (let n = prompt('enter a number'); n >= 2; n--) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    if (n % j === 0) { //if the number is divisible by j increment counter
      counter++;
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  if (counter <= 2) { // if there are two or less numbers divisible then the n is a prime
    alert(n);
  } else {
    continue;
  }
}
```

I tried this in the console but is showed undefined and when I try this in playcode.io it says "Loop Protection: Infinity loop on line 2, char 0. You can disable the Loop Protection in website or console settings."

Comment: So `n` is undefined in the alert? Also why do you never define `counter`? Also `prompt()` returns a string you probably want to make it a number with `Number(prompt())`

Comment: Sijan so do you want to fix this code, or check the prime function?

Comment: I'm sorry while editing the first line got removed and yes, n is undefined for some reason.

Comment: I want to fix it.

Comment: @Sijan this works fine for me in google chrome console window after declaring `var counter=0 ` above the for loop

Comment: ``` let n = Number(prompt('enter a number'));
for (n; n>=2; n--){

Comment: omgggg yess i defined the counter at line 2 and it workss!! thanks everyone<3

Comment: The `alert`, if it triggers, will never display `undefined`. The console will display `undefined` because it always shows the evaluation of the last statement, and `for` statement does not produce a value.

Comment: umm, it worked in the google console but and showed the same infinity loop error in playcode.io

Answer (score -2):

A prompt always returns a string, so you have to convert it to a number first, like this:

`for (let n = Number(prompt('enter a number')); n >= 2; n--) {`

Comment: I do not think this is true, javascript has dynamic casting and it works for me in the console of google chrome

Comment: It is a good practice to explicitly convert, but "have to" is not correct, as StarshipladDev correctly notes. The problem in question is still vague and cannot be reproduced, but it does not lie in wrong value type.

Comment: Also what exactly would happen if the response from prompt wasn't a number at all? this should be dealt with